# Android - ScrollView doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have this Layout created. Inside the LinearLayout there are some TextViews. If i run this on an emulator, I am able to scroll for some seconds after that the activity freezes.(scrolling in listviews works fine!).  Going back in my app to the MainActivity works.

The corresponding java file to this activity, is the default file you will get if you create a new activity in eclipse.

Did I made something wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

 <!-- stuff -->



</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Is there anything in the logcat?

Comment: There is a lot in the logcat. But no fitting error log.

Answer (score 0):

Change   android:layout_height="match_parent" to android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

Change the parent attribute in the themes.xml or styles.xml to this:

```
<style name="dont  touch this" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```